# Scss module (css modules): importing from other scss files

Tags: css, sass, css-modules

I'm currently converting my sass styles to use [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) to avoid style conflicts. My understanding is that it generates unique class names, which makes it hard if I want to target another component (e.g. a child component) defined in a different file.

Say I have a component `Button`, and it imports from a `Button.module.scss` file:

```
// Button.js
import styles from "./Button.module.scss";

export const Button () => <button className={styles.button} />;

// Button.module.scss
.button {
    // relevant styles.
}
```

Now I have another component `ButtonGroup`. Say I want to make the button in the group have margin between them, I would have something like this:

```
// ButtonGroup.module.scss
.buttonGroup {
    display: flex
    &[class~=horizontal] {
        & > .button:not(:first-child) { // still using the same class name
            margin-left: 1rem;
        }
    }
    &[class~=vertical] {
        flex-direction: column;
        & > .button:not(:first-child) { // still using the same class name
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I'm still using the `.button` to target the individual buttons. But this won't work because the child component doesn't actually have `.button` as its class name since it's a generated unique class name.

I could use something like [class^=Button] but that feels hacky and hard to maintain once you have a lot of components. (Also realized it wouldn't work in production.)

Comment: Also any general guide with scss module is greatly appreciated. When I try to research most results are about the `@use` rule...

Comment: Note: `Button.module*s*`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) is not related to SASS or SCSS and has its own set of supported features and keywords. Yes, they can be used together, which I actually do in most my projects. But I avoid having classname dependencies between different files. I'm aware of some features that could be used to share classnames, but avoiding the need for it is probably the best solution. I will in the following section list all potential solutions to your conundrum I can think of; choose what suits you best:

- Solution #1: Never sharing classnames, co-locating styles that belong together and operate on the same classnames.
  In your case this would mean that you only have one scss file relating to buttons `buttons.modules.scss` and both `Button.js` and `ButtonGroup.js` import it.
- Solution #2: exempt shared classnames from the *unique generated name* mechanism by marking them as `:global`. This can be done thus:

```
// button.module.scss

// this will stay a global classname
:global(.button) {
    // the button styles
}

// this will be treated as usual, generating a local name
.icon {
    // some icon stuff
}
```

```
// buttongroup.module.scss
.buttonGroup {
    display: flex;

    // will be resolved as local classname
    &.horizontal {
        flex-direction: row;
        // will be resolved as global classname
        & > :global(.button):not(:first-child) { margin-left: 1rem; }
    }
    &.vertical {
        flex-direction: column;
        & > :global(.button):not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem; }
    }
}
```

- Solution #3: accept anonymous children. You can omit the classname of the children. no one places non-buttons in a button group (might even enforce it in your component code).

```
// buttongroup.module.scss
.buttonGroup {
    display: flex;

    &.horizontal {
        flex-direction: row;
        & > *:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 1rem; }
    }
    &.vertical {
        flex-direction: column;
        & > *:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem; }
    }
}
```

- Solution #4: Reference content from another file. There seems to be some support for a syntax that can reference/import stuff from other files, but I perused the documentation and a few github issue discussions ['import className from fileName'](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/40) ['more'](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/25) ['and more'](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-loader-core/pull/28) without getting any clear answer as to how one would import a local classname from another file. There might be something possible either along those lines [see here](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-loader-core/pull/28):

```
@import button from './button.module.scss';
.buttonGroup {
    display: flex;

    &.horizontal {
        flex-direction: row;
        & > .button:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 1rem; }
    }
    &.vertical {
        flex-direction: column;
        & > .button:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem; }
    }
}
```

...or along those lines [see here](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/40#issuecomment-135655919):

```
:import("./button.module.scss") {
  imported-button: button;
}

.buttonGroup {
    display: flex;

    &.horizontal {
        flex-direction: row;
        & > .imported-button:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 1rem; }
    }
    &.vertical {
        flex-direction: column;
        & > .imported-button:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem; }
    }
}
```

- Solution #5: Have your container component add a class `.button-group-item` to each child and use it to apply the margins instead of the `.button` class.