# Reference classes in other modules when using SCSS modules via Vite

Tags: css, sass, module, vite

I'm thinking about using SCSS modules, powered by Vite, but I'd really like an escape hatch from the strict CSS modules school of thought that prevents a module from referencing classes used in other modules.

More specifically I'd basically like to write something like the following:

```
// icon.module.scss
.icon {}

// button.module.scss
.button {
  .icon {}
}
```

Where the ".icon" selector inside the button module after compilation must be the same as the ".icon" selector found in the icon module.

Is there *any* way to do this?

Comment: Related [question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564099/scss-module-css-modules-importing-from-other-scss-files)